# UIDocumentPickerViewController crashes due to missing iCloud entitlement

Tags: ios, icloud

I'm using a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in my iOS app to allow users to open external files. I have added the relevant iCloud entitlements to my app bundle, and most of the time everything is working great.

However, occasionally the document picker will crash, complaining that the app is missing this iCloud entitlement. I have found experimentally that when this happens, the value of `[NSFileManager defaultManager].ubiquityIdentityToken` is usually nil, so I have guarded my call to the document picker with a check to the `ubiquityIdentityToken` as a temporary measure.

Can anybody shed some light on what might be happening here, and what I can do to avoid this crash? It seems almost totally out of my control.

Comment: Does this happen in production as well? or only while testing

Comment: Yes, it's also happening in production; I'm getting the crash dumps sent to Rollbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happening to my app as well -- I just want to use the File Provider features, and don't support iCloud Drive specifically.

I can't shed any light on why it seems to lose touch with iCloud, but this is not a "crash" -- `[[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] init___]` is throwing an exception, which you can catch with a try/catch block. That is, I suspect your app is crashing with "uncaught exception" -- if you catch it, you can just give an error message.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty new to objective-c and only recently discovered that exceptions can be caught- this might be the best way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by users pirating the app. This can cause an app to have invalid iCloud entitlements, which in turn will make `UIDocumentPickerViewController` throw an exception. So not a bug in UIKit, it's doing the right thing.

Catching the exception might save the app from crashing, but we probably shouldn't help pirates, arrgh?